# Using AMPScript to define which Send Classification to use

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, send-definition

OK, so I find myself in a Marketing Cloud environment where Send Classifications are set up individually for Denmark, Sweden, Germany, Schwitzerland and The Netherlands, but my new, triggered mail is built to dynamically show content based on the [Country Code] in the trigger data extension.

All 5 Send Classifications have external keys, can I assign a Send Classification inside the mail in AMPScript using the external key?

The following needs a rewrite, but hopes this makes what I wish for easy to understand:

```
<!--Script Blok-->
%%[ 
/* Script Blok <div style="display:none"> */

VAR @dyncountry 
SET @dyncountry = UPPERCASE([Country Code]) 

IF @dyncountry == "DK" THEN 
"Use Send Classification with External Key XXXX"  
ELSEIF @dyncountry == "CH" THEN 
...and so on

/*</div>*/
]%%
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible. But if you build a decision split in a journey, you should be able to assign Send Classifications  that way.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) I do not have Journey Builder in my Marketing Cloud setup, so I'll keep looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sender profiles support AMPScript. You need to enable AMPScript support for Sender Profiles by logging case with marketing cloud support. Then write your ampscript to choose from name and email address based on your condition in the sender profile . Then create a send classification using dynamic sender profile and use in your triggered send .

Comment: Send Classification is a combination of Sender Profile, Delivery Profile and Can Spam information, your answer addresses the Sender Profile part, the others are still open.